# CSS and Quoted Printable Decoded Email

Tags: php, html, css

I am using PHP imap to store emails in a database to be read later. The code I am using to store the emails:

```
 $insertquery = $cbecc->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (emailID, emailThreadID, emailBody) VALUES (NULL, :etid, :body)");
        $insertquery->bindParam(":etid", $matches[2]);
        $insertquery->bindParam(':body', imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2));
        $insertquery->execute();
```

I am storing it in the 1.2 format so that when I display it back none of the formatting is lost

The code I am using to display the messages:

```
$emailgetquery = $cbecc->prepare("SELECT * FROM emails");
$emailgetquery->execute();
echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($emailrow = $emailgetquery->fetch()){
    echo "<tr><td>".quoted_printable_decode($emailrow['emailBody'])."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The message is stored in Quoted Printable format. The problem is that the email messages are adding this to the html tag on my website:

```
    <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

Which as far as I can tell each email message starts with. This is breaking my CSS code as far as I can tell.

Is it possible to prevent the email from changing my  tag? Or some CSS to prevent changes? Is it possible to strip it at the database entry stage and not affect the resulting output?

Comment: Just run a string replace on body of email before saving to db.